How can i use a function that is within a function in another file?
I want to setup a dark and light theme for my react app. I have my Sidebar.js, Header.js and Footer.js files in my Components folder which is within the src folder.
My app loads light theme on default and the toggle switch is in the sidebar. If the I try to switch to dark theme, just the sidebar and the body switches, the header and footer remain in light theme.
Sidebar.js
//Sidebar.js
const Sidebar = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(lightTheme);
  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme(prevTheme => (prevTheme === darkTheme ? lightTheme : darkTheme));
  };
  
  return (
    <SubMenuItem as="div" onClick={toggleTheme}>
      {theme === darkTheme ? 'Light Theme' : 'Dark Theme'}
    </SubMenuItem>


How do i get my header and footer to get the state of the toogleTheme?

State is locally stored in this component, so it only affects this component.  Maybe you're looking for useContext to share state more globally?

https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components

Theming often works where you have a base css file that defines your dark and light rules, and then you have a function that can toggle the class on the html element so that every element on the page is affected.
One method to solve with React is to use a custom hook that describes the theme state and provides a theme setter, and then updates the html class name to match the change in that state when one of the radio buttons is clicked.


const { useState, useEffect } = React;

// Custom hook to toggle the theme
function useTheme() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');
  
  // The effect watches for changes in the theme
  // state and toggles the html class to that new theme      
  useEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.className = theme;
  }, [theme]);
  
  return [theme, setTheme];
}

// Another component for testing
function AnotherComponent() {
  return (
    <section className="another">
      I am another component
    </section>
  );
}

// ThemeSelector component
function ThemeSelector() {
  
  // Grab the theme state and the setter from the
  // custom hook
  const [theme, setTheme] = useTheme();

  // Define some radio buttons to toggle the theme
  return (
    <section>
      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="theme"
          value="light"
          onChange={() => setTheme('light')}
          checked={theme === 'light'}
        />
        Light
      </label>
      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="theme"
          value="dark"
          onChange={() => setTheme('dark')}
          checked={theme === 'dark'}
        />
        Dark
      </label>
    </section>
  );
}

// Simple App component
function App() {
  return (
    <main>
      <ThemeSelector />
      <AnotherComponent />
    </main>
  );
}

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<App />);
.dark {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #eee;
}

.light {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
}

.another { margin-top: 1rem; }
<html class="light">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>




Well, you can create Context using Context API (which is dedicated in React) and create a ThemeContext and a ThemeContextProvider, then wrap your components with it and pass that state wherever you want.
You can follow this link's description to get the idea of what you need to do:
Some methods of doing this task...
